# how to make a table of puntations juts for once in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

This is my code
it gives you points if you answered well a question, i want to know how to show all the scoreboard at the end with all the user got points I don't want to save that data anywhere, bc is not necessary, i just want to at the end of each command it tells you how many points you had in that game, but taking into account the other players, and all that within a single command, if I start another, the scores would be 0,
some people told me I could use a dictionary but I don't know how
examples

results

david 6 points

maria 3 points

dharma 2 points

mikey 1 point

```
def check(msg=discord.Message) -> True:
    return msg.content.lower() in answer and msg.channel == ctx.message.channel
try:
    guess = await bot.wait_for('mesage', timeout=6, check=check)
    if guess.content.lower() in answer:
        score += 1
    await ctx.send(f"{guess.author.mention} has {score} pts")
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.send("time over")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save it to some database or even simpler a bot variable, when a user's finished a game save the score and use it to update a dict in the bot... You would need access to the bot instance but it would look something like this, assuming this is in a command:

```py
ctx.bot.scores[ctx.author.name] = score
```

You could then use this to display all the final scores

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) library of python. It helps you store your scores persistant without risking data loss. You can also sort the score entries right in the SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in multiple ways:

1. Using [mySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp) or [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

2. Using [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) files

3. Or by dictionaries

Comment: how can i do it with a dictionary?

Comment: this has to be done in a json file ofc considering you want the data to be stored but you can store username as key, and the score as value.

Comment: you can use the [json](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) library to store the data, and likewise retrieve the data you stored there as well

Comment: Don't use usernames as values for obvious reasons (they can change and they aren't unique). Use id's instead.

Comment: oh yea mb, i remember i faced this issue when i was making my bot. @stijndcl is right, use the ids